# How to convert abc file to a musicxml file using music21?

Tags: python, converters, abc, music21, musicxml

I'm writing my thesis and I need some help to understand how I can convert using `music21` a set of `abc` files to a set of `musicxml` files. I need to write a  automatic stream that helps me to convert all the `notthingam` dataset into a set of `musicxml` file that I'll use to create a database.

I've found this class but I don't know how to manage with it:

```
class ConverterABC(object):

    Simple class wrapper for parsing ABC.

    def __init__(self):
        # always create a score instance
        self._stream = stream.Score()

    def parseData(self, strData, number=None):

        # Get ABC data, as token list, from a string representation.
        # If more than one work is defined in the ABC data, a
        # :class:`~music21.stream.Opus` object will be returned;
        # otherwise, a :class:`~music21.stream.Score` is returned.

        af = abc.ABCFile()
        # do not need to call open or close
        abcHandler = af.readstr(strData, number=number)
        # set to stream
        if abcHandler.definesReferenceNumbers():
            # this creates an Opus object, not a Score object
            self._stream = abc.translate.abcToStreamOpus(abcHandler,
                number=number)
        else: # just one work
            abc.translate.abcToStreamScore(abcHandler, self._stream)

    def parseFile(self, fp, number=None):
        # Get MIDI data from a file path.  
        # If more than one work is defined in the ABC data,  
        # a  :class:`~music21.stream.Opus` object will be returned;  
        # otherwise, a :class:`~music21.stream.Score` is returned.

        # If `number` is provided, and this ABC file defines multiple works with a X: tag, just the specified work will be returned.

        #environLocal.printDebug(['ConverterABC.parseFile: got number', number])

        af = abc.ABCFile()
        af.open(fp)
        # returns a handler instance of parse tokens
        abcHandler = af.read(number=number)
        af.close()

        # only create opus if multiple ref numbers
        # are defined; if a number is given an opus will no be created
        if abcHandler.definesReferenceNumbers():
            # this creates a Score or Opus object, depending on if a number
            # is given
            self._stream = abc.translate.abcToStreamOpus(abcHandler,
                           number=number)
        # just get a single work
        else:
            abc.translate.abcToStreamScore(abcHandler, self._stream)

    def _getStream(self):
        return self._stream

    stream = property(_getStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in there https://wim.vree.org/js/index.html is converting XML to ABC and ABC to SVG(signals). Take a look at, maybe it helps you to convert ABC to XML.